# Python list all unicode characters that are in a subset of languages outside of English

Tags: python

I'm training a reverse denoising autoencoder on words of multiple languages. In order to create the input, output I need a list of all possible unicode and ascii characters in Python that are possible. My data does include characters such as 'ó','é', '’', '‘' and '€' as well as many others that I haven't completely looked into as the data is 300,000 rows. The languages I know that my data encompass are Russian, Italian, Dutch, Czech and English.

My dictionary so far is

```
[c for c in string.printable] + [chr(i) for i in range(1000, 1100)] + ['’', 'ó']
```

but this does not encompass all the letters I need sadly.

Comment: You can get a full list of the latin unicode characters on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_script_in_Unicode) and then add each range that you require `[chr(i) for i in range(0x0021, 0x02FF)]`

Comment: "characters such as 'ó','é' and a weird apostrophe that is not in string.printable" are not criteria that can be used directly.  You need to identify the [subsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Standardized_subsets) that you require and add the codepoints in those ranges.

Comment: @usr2564301 but some of the characters I listed are not listed in Unicode Wikipedia for those languages. Also what maybe trivial to one person may not be trivial to others.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I listed the characters I have seen that are not standard. I cannot list a full subset as the data is 300,000 rows long. Unless you expect me to go through it and get every character that isn't in ascii. Then I wouldn't need to post this question would I?

Comment: The ascii like latin characters fall into 5 main ranges Basic Latin (0021–007F), Latin-1 Suppliment (0080–00FF), Latin Extended A (0100–017F), Latin Extended B (0180–024F.) and Latin Extended Additional(1E00–1EFF)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a full list of the latin unicode characters on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_script_in_Unicode) and then add each range that you require

```py
[chr(i) for i in range(0x0021, 0x02FF)]
```

The ranges you are probably interested in are:

- Basic Latin (0021–007F)
- Latin-1 Suppliment (0080–00FF)
- Latin Extended A (0100–017F)
- Latin Extended B (0180–024F)
- Latin Extended Additional(1E00–1EFF)

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to look at it in terms of the languages represented in the data. One approach is to utilise information available in the Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR). CLDR contains information on exemplar and auxiliary characters for each locale. Exemplar characters are characters likely to be found in text and data in that language/locale. This may be more than what is in the language's alphabet, which may exclude some letters with diacritics, or letters used in loanwords. Auxiliary characters are additional characters that may be observed.

I will use PyICU to illustrate:

```py
from icu import LocaleData, ULocaleDataExemplarSetType as ExemplarType
languages = ["cs", "en", "it", "nl", "ru"]
letters = []
for language in languages:
    ld = LocaleData(language)
    us = ld.getExemplarSet(ExemplarType.ES_STANDARD)
    letters = [*letters, *us]
letters = sorted(list(set(letters)))
print(letters)
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'ch', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'ij', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
# 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'à', 'á', 'ä',
# 'è', 'é', 'ë', 'ì', 'í', 'íj́', 'ï', 'ò', 'ó', 'ö', 'ù', 'ú', 'ü', 'ý', 'č', 'ď',
# 'ě', 'ň', 'ř', 'š', 'ť', 'ů', 'ž', 'а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ж', 'з', 'и',
# 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш',
# 'щ', 'ъ', 'ы', 'ь', 'э', 'ю', 'я', 'ё']
```

The code creates a `LocaleData` instance, then gets the exemplar characters as a `UnicodeSet` object. We add the Unicode set to a list.

At this point, the list will have multiple copies of letters that various languages have in common, so we create a set of the letters, then convert it back to a list and sort it.

It will also contain digraphs. It is possible to split digraphs into their individual components:

```py
import re
from icu import LocaleData, ULocaleDataExemplarSetType as ExemplarType

languages = ["cs", "it", "nl", "ru"]

def character_requirements(languages, ngraphs=False, basic_latin=False):
    letters = []
    for language in languages:
        ld = LocaleData(language)
        us = ld.getExemplarSet(ExemplarType.ES_STANDARD)
        letters = [*letters, *us]
    if not ngraphs:
        letters = list("".join(letters))
    if not basic_latin:
        pattern = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]')
        letters = [i for i in letters if not pattern.search(i)]
    letters = sorted(list(set(letters)))
    return letters

chars = character_requirements(languages)
print(chars)
# ['à', 'á', 'ä', 'è', 'é', 'ë', 'ì', 'í', 'ï', 'ò', 'ó', 'ö', 'ù',
# 'ú', 'ü', 'ý', 'č', 'ď', 'ě', 'ň', 'ř', 'š', 'ť', 'ů', 'ž', '́', 'а',
# 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ж', 'з', 'и', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н',
# 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ъ',
# 'ы', 'ь', 'э', 'ю', 'я', 'ё']
```